# Как настроить meta теги в react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, seo

Работаю с приложением на React, роутинг на react router. Появилась нужда в сео оптимизации и добавлении на каждую страницу приложения своих мета тегов. Попробовал react helmet, но валидатор микроразметки яндекс (https://webmaster.yandex.ru/tools/microtest/) эти динамические meta теги не видит, видит только те что были заданы в index.html.
При переходе на страницу в браузере все заданные meta теги естественно подгружаются.

Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему, не прибегая к ssr? Или для гугловского поисковика этих динамических тегов достаточно для индексации и можно не переживать?

Comment: Получилось решить вопрос?

Comment: Нашел решение ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить атрибут в файл index.html в meta тег(и) -> data-react-helmet="true" и все перезаписывается.